# Rails 3.1.4 - Render :text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm updating my rails 2 apps to rails 3 and find that the use of 'render :text' does not behave the same anymore.

@results is an array. In my controller:

```
render :text => "<ul>#{@results}</ul>"
```

It's returning the whole array as a string rather than iterating through each value:

```
<ul>
  ["
  <li>Steve</li>
  ", "
  <li>John</li>
  "]
</ul>
```

Worked fine in Rails 2.x but not in 3. How do I fix this?

I'm expecting a result of:

```
<ul>
  <li>Steve</li>
  <li>John</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 32):

I know this question is for Rails 3.1.4 only.

But those who come here and are on a more recent version, starting with Rails 5.1 we'll do this:

```
render plain: "I'm like everyone else."
```

Comment: Nice. Note that this sets the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain` (among the charset). If you came here looking for how to render HTML (but not in a template file), use `render html: '<div>...</div>'`. That sets the header to `text/html` and your browser will know to parse the hTML. (Potentially call `.html_safe` on your html string, but be careful.)

Answer (score 10):

The string contains HTML tags so you will need to mark it as safe so that Rails doesn't escape the tags.

```
render :text => "<ul>#{@results}</ul>".html_safe
```

NOTE: Unless there is a valid reason to have HTML in your controller, I recommend moving the list items to a view.

6/23/2014 UPDATE: In retrospect, I don't like having this string parsing logic in the controller. The `@results` suggests there is HTML embedded in an object somewhere. I recommend using a presentation object and call a method like `@results.list`. The Draper gem is well-suited for this.

Cite

- https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing the following instead of render :text

```
render :partial => "result", :collection => @results
```

and add the file: _result.html.erb with

```
<ul>
  <%= result %>
</ul>
```

or even better if you can remove the li tags from @results

```
<ul>
  <li><%= result %></li>
</ul>
```

The Rails 3 docs say render text should be used for NON HTML text, which does not fit your use case.  Using render :partial :collection is a better and more rails 3 way to iterate through your list.