# Why render plain: instead of render: plain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

[The tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) I'm doing says to input the following code into my controller:

```
def create
  render plain: params[:article].inspect
end
```

How come the colon comes after plain and [not before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935655/rails-3-1-4-render-text)? I know plain represents `plain_text`, but how come it just doesen't say `text` instead?. `render :text` would make a lot more sense than `render plain`

Comment: It's a symbol used as a hash key, and the value of that hash entry is what comes next. Re: text v plain, there are multiple kinds of text MIME types, whereas `text/plain`, e.g., `plain:`, is unambiguous.

Comment: Remember: Guide is about Rails 4, the question you referenced is about Rails 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a key in a hash, using the new hash syntax. It's exactly equivalent to `render { :plain => params[:article].inspect }`

As for why it's `:plain` and not `:text`... because it is. You *thinking* that `text:` is better is purely subjective, and way off-topic for this site.

Comment: Completely unclear from your answer, please note that up until rails 5 `render text:` was a completely valid synonym for `render plain:`. In rails 5 it was deprecated and removed.